# Dropdownlist problem

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I don't understand why I can't get the ddl selected value..

ASP CODE:

```
<table>
    <tr>
      <th> Annee:</th>
         <td>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAnnee" runat="server" />
         </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th colspan="2">
         <asp:Button ID="btnValidate" runat="server" onclick="btnValidate_Click" 
                                    Text="Validate"  />
       </th>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Code BEHIND:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                BindControls();
            }
        }

        public void BindControls()
        {
            this.ddlAnnee.DataSource = new BLL.ANNEE_MANAGER().List(false, true, null);
            this.ddlAnnee.DataTextField = "INTITULE_AN";
            this.ddlAnnee.DataValueField = "ID_AN";
            this.ddlAnnee.DataBind();
        }

        protected void btnValidate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int Id_an = int.Parse( this.ddlAnnee.SelectedValue);

        }
    }
}
```

So, when i put a break point at the page load and binding part, it's ok, the ddl is filled correctly and the page show correctly the ddl. When I click on the button, I arrive in the btnValidate_Click method but the ddl is empy!

I suppose I've forgot something.. Please help me!

Thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not remove IsPostBack, the BindControl method should be in !IsPostBack Condition otherwise you are never going to get selected value. Just make sure that any of the method not clearing the ddlAnnee dropdown.

Comment: In fact I always have the first value of ddl if I delete the !IspostBack condition. But How can i make sure about the clearing?

Comment: The given code is working fine for me in framework 3.5 or above. Which framework you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `IsPostBack` check - when you click the button the code is not refilling the drop down so it is empty and the selected value no longer exists.

Comment: Yes, thanks it's work but the value is always the first now, whenever i change the ddl, value always take the first entry in the ddl..

Answer (score 0):

You have to bind the grid both on a fresh page load and on a postback.

Answer (score 0):

i Think That when you click the button then page load performed and you calearing the all the data from ddl at the click or after performing son action so when click event performed and you had put the bindcontrol() under the  ISPOSTBACK  requirements ddl are going to bind the first time when page is load so change the code according the requirements.